# Typing text animation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hopefully someone can help me with this. I am kinda new to jQuery, but I'm trying to figure out a way to create an animated typing text effect for an entire div class! A long google search has only given me small plugins, although they are great... They just don't do what I need them to do… (or I just don't have the education to set it up)…

Basically, as soon as the page loads I need to have an entire pre-existing div class inside a block of html (I don't want the text to be provided by the JS) start to ‘type’ out the text as a human would, keeping all CSS of the internal elements (h1s, h2s, p, spans, etc.) and in the order that they are in the flow of the page.

This is the file I'm working on
http://jsfiddle.net/we9d81jf/

```
var $el = $('.typing'),
    txt = $el.text(),
    txtLen = txt.length,
    timeOut,
    char = 0;

$el.text('|');

(function typeIt() {   
    var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        char++;
        var type = txt.substring(0, char);
        $el.text(type + '|');
        typeIt();

        if (char == txtLen) {
            $el.text($el.text().slice(0, -1)); // remove the '|'
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }

    }, humanize);

}());
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, if you want to see the effects of html tags use `.html` instead of `.text()`.
Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/we9d81jf/7/).

Comment: The issue with this is the '<' which appears initially. Let me know if this was useful till then let's try to resolve this issue.

Comment: That looks amazing.. I knew it was something so small that it was stupid of me to not figure out myself... The '<' part probably isn't a huge deal... as I probably will speed up the animation so the user might not even see it.... but hypothetically... say i want this 100% perfect, how could we rectify this little issue?

Comment: Any more help regarding the '<' which appears initially.... I have been mucking around with the code and I think I have only made it worse.... I am trying to figure out if creating the html elements in the javascript and appending the characters of the text would fix this issue... but I can't even find a decent way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use jQuery plugin such as [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/). It works perfect, the '<' and '>' won't  display. You can also dive into the [source code](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/js/typed.js) to find out how it work.

This is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/p4ev1nj2/3/)(The string contains `<br>` and you can add some tag to test it).